# PHP timestamp comparison

Tags: php, timestamp

```
$today      = mktime(0,0,0,2, 9, 2011);
$today >= $r['arrival_date'] // false
9 >= date('j', $r['arrival_date']) // true

$r['arival_date'] is 1297227600 [Feb 9, 2011 07:00]
```

Comment: what does  `var_dump($r['arrival_date'])` show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
$today = mktime(0,0,0,2, 9, 2011); // = 1297209600
```

and

```
$r['arival_date'] = 1297227600;
```

so

```
1297227600 > 1297209600
```

because

```
date('H',$r['arrival_date']); // 7
date('H',$today); // 0
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand and explain upon Andre Matos' answer, `mktime(0,0,0,2,9,2011);` is `00:00:00 Feb 9 2011`, basically the first instant of Feb 9, and the Arrival Date is `07:00:00 Feb 9 2011`, 7 hours later, so it's timestamp is greater than the one created by mktime.

To check whether or not a timestamp falls within a specific day, you can check in a few different ways:

```
//You can check by adding a day onto the timestamp for today, 24*60*60 is one days worth of seconds (86400 seconds)
if($r['arrival_date'] >= $today && $r['arrival_date'] <= $today + (24*60*60))

//Or you can mktime for tomorrow too.  
$tomorrow = mktime(0,0,0,2,10,2011);
if($r['arrival_date'] >= $today && $r['arrival_date'] <= $tomorrow)

//Or you could check the way you have up there, by running it through date and checking if one is equivalent to another
//Or you could do strtotime in there somewhere, or whatever
```

That's just a couple of the easiest.  Basically since timestamps are down to the second (specifically seconds since `00:00:00 Jan 1 1970 UTC`), you're gonna have to check them by range.

Comment: Actually I think that you should use `<` instead of `<=`, otherwise if arrival_date is tomorrow at 00:00 it would still be true for being today